# Newhouse Ruelle Takens theorem and three frequency quasiperiodicty

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

NRT theorem suggests that there exist arbitrarily small perturbations of a vector field on an $m$-torus for $m\geq3$ leading to strange axiom A attractors. Although, three frequency quasi periodic motion exists in nature. Can someone explain how this is possible. And please suggest where i can find more about the probability of occurrence of such attractors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NRT's theorem, but do they prove that *some* perturbations lead to strange attractors or that *generic* perturbations lead to strange attractors? if it's the first case, then I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki they prove that in every neighborhood(arbitrarily small) of the given vector field, there is some vector field with gives rise to a strange attractor

Comment: @AnkurNashkar OK, then what's the problem?quasiperiodic motion exists in nature. OK. some perturbations of quasiperiodic motion gives  a different behaviour (strange attractors). we can still observe quasiperiodic motion in nature because presumably there are lots of other perturbations of quasiperiodic motion that give something topologically conjugate to quasiperiodic motion.